# Not connecting to MySQL remotely

Tags: mysql, linux, shell, terminal

I've been trying to connect to my MySQL Server remotely and not getting any success. The terminal gets stuck and neither gives me an error message. If I insert the password wrong I get `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user`, so I believe MySQL/Server are getting my connection. Locally in the server I can connect with the same user without any issues.
I am connecting to an AWS Ubuntu 16.04, and got the same problem at Azure Debian 8.

Here are the steps I've taken so far:

- Commented out `#bind-address` at `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`
- Ran `sudo ufw allow 'MySQL'` and `sudo ufw allow 'MySQLServer'`
- Allowed Inbound connection at port 3306
- Ran `iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT`
- `lsof -Pni :3306` returns

`mysqld  12118 mysql   16u  IPv6  38112      0t0  TCP *:3306 (LISTEN)`

- Create user with

  `CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`
  `CREATE USER 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`
  `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'user'@'localhost';`
  `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'user'@'%';`
  `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

When connecting I'm running `mysql -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -u user -ppassword`
and the terminal process "freezes".
If anyone can help please.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of commenting out `bind-address`, change it to:

> bind-address = 0.0.0.0

And also drop the `-ppassword` and make it just `-p`, that errors out by default.

I was able to connect to a MySQL instance running on an Ubuntu 16.04 server on AWS after following the same steps you followed with that single difference.

Comment: Have you tried using mysql workbench or sequel pro to connect to it, is your terminal hanging still the problem you're having?